# mysql, Accent insensitive

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

according to : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-names.html

```
"latin1_general_ci is explicitly case insensitive and implicitly accent insensitive"
```

**test 1**

```
SET @a =_latin1'é' COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
SET @b =_latin1'e' COLLATE latin1_general_ci; 
SELECT @a=@b; # returns 0
```

**test 2**

```
SET @a =_latin1'é' COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
SET @b =_latin1'É' COLLATE latin1_general_ci; 
SELECT @a=@b; # returns 0
```

looks like it is not working correctly, why?